# How to update a specific line and column in a matrix in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a matrix in react native:

```
const [matrix, setMatrix] = useState([
      [0,0,0,0],
      [0,0,0,0],
      [0,0,0,0],
      [0,0,0,0],
]);
```

How can I use `setMatrix` to update a specific line and column in the matrix?

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
let newMatrix = matrix
newMatrix[xIndex] = [1,1,1,1]
setMatrix(newMatrix)
```

Or

```
let newMatrix = matrix
newMatrix[xIndex][yIndex] = 1
setMatrix(newMatrix)
```

Answer (score 0):

In react, your goal is to treat your state as immutable. As an array is mutable, you'll need to make a copy of it before you change it. This can be done by passing a callback to `setMatrix()`. Here you can access the previous matrix state allowing you to modify it. To make the copy, you can map each inner array to a new array and then update the copied matrix.

See example below:

```
setMatrix(oldMatrix => {
  const matrixCopy = oldMatrix.map(([...row]) => row); // clone oldMatrix
  const row = 1; // row to update
  const col = 2; // column to update
  matrixCopy[row][col] = 1; // update your copied array
  return matrixCopy; // return the new state.
});
```

You could also consider using the node package [immer](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/introduction) which provides an easier way to work with treating state as immutable:

```
const produce = require("immer");
...
const updateMatrixFn = produce(matrixCopy => {
  const row = 1; // row to update
  const col = 2; // column to update
  matrixCopy[row][col] = 1; // update your copied array
});
setMatrix(updateMatrixFn);
```